# Uploading a pdf document in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, pdf

I am trying to upload pdf document and part of the code is to get the `contentUri`

ContentUri is always null as the type `document` is not specified in the when section.

uri passed is `content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/document%3A26936`

I get the documentId and the type is `document`

How can I get contentUri for the document type please

here is the code I have at the moment

```
 isMediaDocument(uri) -> {
                    val docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri)
                    val split = docId.split(":").toTypedArray()
                    val type = split[0]
                    var contentUri: Uri? = null
                    when (type) {
                        "image" -> {
                            contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
                        }
                        "video" -> {
                            contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
                        }
                        "audio" -> {
                            contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
                        }
                    }
                    val selection = "_id=?"
                    val selectionArgs = arrayOf(split[1])
                    return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs)
                }
```

[image]

please suggest what is the right way of doing this please

Thanks
R

Comment: You already have the `Uri`. "please suggest what is the right way of doing this please" -- delete the code from the question and use the `Uri`. For example, you can upload [using OkHttp and a `Uri`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/07/05/multipart-upload-okttp-uri.html).

Comment: Sorry if i made it confusing, contentUri is always null cuz received `type` is `document` and I do not have a case for that in when clause.
how can i resolve this please

Comment: `content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/document%3A26936` is a `Uri`. Use it with OkHttp/Retrofit and an `InputStreamRequestBody` implementation, such as the ones mentioned in [the blog post that I linked to](https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/07/05/multipart-upload-okttp-uri.html).